# Can I create a Dictionary of Funcs that vary in their first argument?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a bunch of static methods that all have the same signature, except for the type of their first argument, for example:

```
public static class ElementCreators
{
    public static XmlElement CreateElementForString
               (string s, string name, string namespaceURI)
    {
        [...]
    }

    public static XmlElement CreateElementForDecimal
               (Decimal d, string name, string namespaceURI)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

I want to create a Dictionary (or some sort of lookup that can be modified at runtime - people are supposed to be able to add their own funcs, though once a func is added, it doesn't need to be modified/removed, and there are never two+ funcs for a given type. There might be funcs for base and derived types, but in that case, it's up to the user to register them e.g., in the right order) to dispatch based on the type, e.g.:

```
var funcs = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string, string, XmlElement>>();
funcs[typeof(string)] = ElementCreators.CreateElementForString;
funcs[typeof(Decimal)] = ElementCreators.CreateElementForDecimal;
```

Now, this doesn't work, as there is no contravariance between delegates, so the compiler complains that `CS0123 No overload for 'CreateElementForString' matches delegate 'Func<object, string, string, XmlElement>'`.

One option is to create another delegate as the middle-man:

```
funcs[typeof(string)] =
            (o,s1,s2) => ElementCreators.CreateElementForString((string)o, s1, s2);
```

That works, but is a) ugly and b) introduces a bunch of unnecessary delegates.

Generics don't seem to be an option, because the Func can not be of an open type T. Similarly, dynamic doesn't work, but I don't want to use these anyway (runtime cost).

I could introduce a level of indirection for each method, which avoids the delegate, but it isn't any less ugly:

```
public static XmlElement CreateElementForString(object s, string name, string namespaceURI)
    => CreateElementForString((string)s, name, namespaceURI);
```

And of course, I could try automating something like that (T4 templates, Pre-Build task, custom Build Action, etc.)

But before I do that, I wonder if there's a better way that I've overlooked?

Visual Studio 2017, .NET 4.7.1, and C# 7.2 are all available for this.

Comment: Reason the other way; suppose you did manage to make a dictionary from `Type` to `something`. How are you going to invoke the `something`? If you're going to invoke it via reflection (or dynamic) then what does it matter what the value type of the dictionary is? It could be `object`, or `dynamic` or `System.Delegate` or whatever; you're getting no compile-time safety on the call site, so why worry about it in the dictionary?

Comment: @EricLippert When you put it like that, it makes sense. Indeed, it would be defeating the compiler check and rely on the user not lying when they say that the passed in object can be casted to the argument type, but the language supports that through explicit casting, not through any implicit conversion. I'll think of a better way to at least enforce compiler checks.

Comment: Yea it's just way too much work to deal with T4 templates/build task/custom tools for this extra level of type safety. Just create a helper method like `private void SetDelegate<T>(Func<T, string, string> f) => funcs[typeof(T)] = (o, s1, s2) => f((T)o, s1, s2);`, write some good unit tests, and be done with it.

Comment: Delegate types can have contravariance, for example `Func<in T1, in T2, in T3, out TResult>` is contravariant ("`in`") in `T1`, but I do not think it will help you. Also, conversions from methods to delegates (possibly non-generic delegates) can be contravariant, but again I do not think it will help. And in either case, the contravariance will not help with `object` to `decimal` because the latter is a value type (not supported by any variance in C#/.NET).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments cover, not really.  But you can build a class that accomplishes what you want (relatively type safe, pleasant to use) I think.

```
public class DelegateDictionary
{
    Dictionary<Type, Delegate> Lookup;

    public DelegateDictionary()
    {
        Lookup = new Dictionary<System.Type, Delegate>();
    }

    public void Add<T>(Func<T, string, string, XmlElement> mtd)
    {
        Lookup.Add(typeof(T), mtd);
    }

    public XmlElement Invoke<T>(T value, string name, string namespaceURI)
    {
        if (!Lookup.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var del)) throw new InvalidOperationException($"No delegate registered for {typeof(T).Name}");

        var typedDel = (Func<T, string, string, XmlElement>)del;
        return typedDel(value, name, namespaceURI);
    }
}
```

You do have to type the `Add(...)` call, it can't be inferred), but the `Invoke(...)` can be inferred (and presumably there are more invocations than registrations).

```
// example usage
{
    var dict = new DelegateDictionary();

    dict.Add<string>(ElementCreators.CreateElementForString);
    dict.Add<Decimal>(ElementCreators.CreateElementForDecimal);

    dict.Invoke("stringValue", "myName", "what-even-is-a-namespace");
    dict.Invoke(1.0m, "myName", "what-even-is-a-namespace");
}
```

I don't think you'll pay for anything besides the cast on invoke, but haven't profiled to confirm.

Answer (score 4):

If you can be whole program `static`/global then you can use a very fast compile time dictionary (no-lookup) and generics (no boxing):

```
class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        // Set up defaults; lambda rather than Method group (allocs)
        ElementCreators<string>.CreateElement = (s, name, namespaceURI)
                => ElementCreators.CreateElement(s, name, namespaceURI);
        ElementCreators<Decimal>.CreateElement = (d, name, namespaceURI)
                => ElementCreators.CreateElement(d, name, namespaceURI);

        // Call
        XmlElement xml = ElementCreators<string>.CreateElement("hello", "name", "ns");
    }

}

public static class ElementCreators<T>
{
    // Can change property get to throw KeyNotFound if null
    public static Func<T, string, string, XmlElement> CreateElement { get; set; }
}


public static class ElementCreators
{
    public static XmlElement CreateElement(string s, string name, string namespaceURI)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static XmlElement CreateElement(Decimal d, string name, string namespaceURI)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done this to great effect, and other than FxCop/compiler complaints about generic arguments on type definitions it works great.

Comment: That is interesting, thanks! Yeah, the Dictionary is static, though I need to be able to add to it at runtime. That said, most if it is setup at compile time (the idea is that a user can "override" funcs), so this will actually solve the common case. Will give it a try tomorrow!

Comment: The issue its a static class so you can't have multiple without creating a new static class; so its a very global type dictionary (and will never be GC'd)

Comment: I went with Kevin's suggestion because it fits my use case a bit better, but this here also works very well!

Comment: Yeah its less flexible as it only works for a very narrow usecase; but is very fast if you have that usecase. A bad approach for libraries however (due to single instance)